# ER Diagram, Ternary Relationship Zero to Many

Tags: entity-relationship, erd

I need help with the ER diagram. I'm trying to depict the following:

One person can apply for many vacations.
One vacation can have many persons.
For a certain vacation, a certain person can write zero or many inquiries. And one vacation can have zero or many inquires

I made an entity called `Person_Vacation` with primary key consisting of `person_id` and `vacation_id`. But I'm unsure what to do with `inquiry_id` in this situation.

[image]